# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference. Invalid API address Crash

Tags: java, android

I'm still kinda new to Android programming and I've been trying to make a simple weather app, for practice. This code works fine when I enter a valid city name, however I want to use a `toast` that shows an error to the user when the name is not valid. But this results in a crash, I tried removing the `toast`, but my app still crashes.

Here's the **code**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText cityName;
TextView resultTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    cityName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cityName);
    resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);

}


public void findWeather(View view)
{
    Log.i("Button", "pressed");


    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(cityName.getWindowToken(), 0);



    try {

        String encodedCityName = URLEncoder.encode(cityName.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        task.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + encodedCityName +"&appid=***");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find city", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

    }

}


public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;

        try {
            url = new URL(strings[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int data = reader.read();
            while(data != -1)
            {
                char current = (char) data;
                result += current;
                data = reader.read();
            }
            return  result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        try{
            String message = "";
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
            String weatherInfo = jsonObject.getString("weather");
            Log.i("weather", weatherInfo);

            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(weatherInfo);

            for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                String main = "";
                String description = "";

                main = jsonPart.getString("main");
                description = jsonPart.getString("description");

                if (!main.isEmpty() && !description.isEmpty())
                {
                    message += main + ": " + description + "\r\n";

                }
            }

            if(!message.isEmpty())
            {
                resultTextView.setText(message);

            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find city", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

and the **error mesage**:

> 12-22 22:11:51.204 4858-4858/com.example.aiden.whatstheweather
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: com.example.aiden.whatstheweather, PID: 4858
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
>                                                                                        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
>                                                                                        at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:159)
>                                                                                        at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:176)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.example.aiden.whatstheweather.MainActivity$DownloadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:102)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.example.aiden.whatstheweather.MainActivity$DownloadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:65)
>                                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
>                                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                                                        at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: what is the log value you are getting with this line   Log.i("weather", weatherInfo);

Comment: Add your api response in the question, so that it'd be easier for people to debug your code.

Comment: This error can also come from "empty string", e.g in this code `    URL u = new URL(xml_file);
                        URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();` if *xml_file* is empty, the second line with generate error. Make sure to set it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If any exception occur in `doInBackground()` its going to return `null`. Handle it as below.

```
  @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
   if(s!=null){
    // Do you work here on success
  }else{
     // null response or Exception occur 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If `doInBackground` catches exception, it will only print the stack trace and then return `null`. The `null` is then passed to `onPostExecute`. The `JSONObject` pick the `null` and hence the crash. So it'd be better to return empty value than `null`.

In `DownloadTask.doInBackground`, change

```
return null;
```

to

```
return "";
```